# Table Structure for alternative to storing an array in a single MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am currently building a car booking system using PDO PHP and MySQL but am struggling with how to structure my tables for any car extras the user may have added to their booking.

I currently have the following tables at the moment which use the reservation_table to link the booking_id with the car_id (taken from their separate tables):

car_table:

```
ID     | car_make | car_name
1      | Ford     | Focus
2      | BMW      | Z3
3      | Audi     | A5
```

booking_table:

```
booking_ID  | booking_time | total_cost | etc..
125674      | 2013-02-02   | 91.55     
887463      | 2013-01-19   | 52.00     
209930      | 2013-01-11   | 23.99
```

reservation_table:

```
ID     | booking_ID | car_ID
1      | 125674     | 2
2      | 887463     | 2
3      | 209930     | 1
```

extras_table:

```
ID     | car_extra     | extra_price
1      | GPS           | 22.99
2      | Baby Seat     | 12.99
3      | Car Charger   | 15.99
```

Originally I was going to add an extra column into the reservation_table using an array of the selected car extras to link them with the booking as so:
booking_table:

```
ID     | booking_ID | car_ID | car_extras
1      | 125674     | 2      | [2,3]
2      | 887463     | 2      | [1]
3      | 209930     | 1      | [1,3]
```

but I have read that this is bad practice. How can I structure my tables so that I can assign the selected car extra ID's (which can range from the user selecting 0 to 12) to a particular booking?

Would the following work by creating a new table that linked just the booking_ID with the extra_ID (this would mean multiple rows of the same booking id though):

selected_extras_table:

```
ID     | booking_ID | car_extra_ID
1      | 125674     | 2
2      | 125674     | 3
3      | 887463     | 1
4      | 209930     | 1
5      | 209930     | 3
```

Comment: Your `selected_extras_table` is how I would suggest doing it. If each car can have only one of any available extra you can do away with the surrogate key `ID` and have a composite index on `booking_ID` and `car_extra_ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exactly right: creating the selected_extras_table with a row per extra is the best solution. When you query that table, you'll get a list of all the extras in whichever booking_ID you're interested in, and you won't need to parse out multiple values from a single field (e.g., "[2,3]"). Let the database keep the values separate. You're on the right track.